# complex operator

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry

I have asked this question before. I deleted it as no one answered it and I received negative feedback. Though I didn't understand what is going on now I think I do. I just want to verify my solution and also ask about complex structure on $T_U,u$. This is my question again.

I started learning things from Claire Voisin. I am confused about how the author arrived at 1.3 from 1.1 (partial Solution below). I am also confused about the natural complex structure on , can someone explain that part as well?

We know that $\frac{\partial}{\partial z} = a \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + b \frac{\partial}{\partial y}$.

Therefore

$\frac{\partial x}{\partial z} = a$.

We also know that $a = dx = \frac{1}{2}(dz + d\bar{z})$. Similarly we know that $b = dy = \frac{1}{2i}(dz - d\bar{z})$.

Therefore $\frac{\partial}{\partial z} = \frac{1}{2}(dz + d\bar{z}) - \frac{i}{2}(dz - d\bar{z}) = \frac{1}{2} (dz - i dz) + \frac{1}{2}(d\bar{z} + id\bar{z})$.

I think I am almost there though little bit confused.

[image]

Comment: Where is your earlier question, and why didn't you edit *that* question, rather than the same question yet again?

Comment: @amWhy I deleted it as no one answered it and I received negative feedback.

Comment: Do not delete a post and turn around and repost it.  Your task is to improve the original post, based on feedback, etc.. Deleting poor posts can backfire, and contribute to a question ban.  And deleting in order to repost is considered "gaming the system".

Comment: It was closed. Though I have added more details now.

Comment: Though I will not do that again. I didn't know that thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{\partial}{\partial z} = \frac{1}{2}(dz + d\bar{z}) - \frac{i}{2}(dz - d\bar{z})$ is nonsense (LHS is a differential operator, RHS is a differential form and they are dual to one another but not the same type of objects) and denotes a lack of understanding of basic differential calculus.

For the derivation of 1.3 from 1.1, one notices that 1.1 implies $dz=dx+idy, d\bar z=dx-idy$ so using that by definition we must have $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ is the dual of $dz$ and all the rest of similar duality results between the other $3$ variables $x,y, \bar z$, we need to invert the matrix of change of variables from $dx,dy$ to $dz, d\bar z$ and get 1.3

Or if matrix computation is mysterious, just do it by hand with $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}=a\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+bi\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ using $<\frac{\partial}{\partial z}, dz>=1, <\frac{\partial}{\partial z}, d\bar z>=0$ and get $a-b=1, a+b=0$ giving $a=1/2, b=-1/2$ as expected; same for the other one, or just use conjugation noticing that $\overline {\frac{\partial}{\partial z}}=\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar z}$ while $\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ are real operators so conjugate invariant and only the $i$ changes sign

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you make a comment about the matridx computation as it is mysterious to me? Can you also tell me about the complex structure on $T_U,u$?